# Writing formal letter (email) to big companies

Tags: formality, email

I am from a non-English video game site (press) and I want to write a formal email to some of big video gaming companies (developers and publishers) and ask them for cooperation in press coverage.

How should I write them a formal email? How should I start my email? Which Phrases are good to show my purpose? Should I speak from myself (with I Pronoun) or from the entire team (with We Pronoun)? Is there any good Articles about writing formal letters to companies?

Thanks

Comment: This question might be too broad and primarily opinion-based, so might be closed. Try searching [How to write a formal letter](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+a+formal+letter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Afterwards, if you have a specific concern, then it should be ok to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since email evolved from physical letter writing, the most formal emails follow the rules from formal letter writing. As Max mentioned in his comment, use the rules for formal letters to make your email formal.

You can probably skip the date and full address from paper letters since this is included in email metadata, but start with a salutation of the full name of the person or use 'Sirs:' or 'Dear Sirs:' if addressing a group of people. If your letter represents a company or group of people use 'we' but if only yourself use 'I'.  Finish with your full name, title/company, and contact info.

The best letters are short and to the point, and give the reader some reason to cooperate. If your non-English site were for example German, you might include the sentence "We are excited to give our German readers information about your game.'  This tells them that in return for cooperation with you they will be able to sell more copies of their game to a market segment that otherwise might never hear of them.